# Правильная реализация Dispose вместе с SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid

Tags: c#, .net, шаблоны-проектирования, dll

В сети есть много примеров реализации паттерна Dispose применительно к оберткам для C++ DLL, но все они немного отличаются, такое ощущение, что многие просто перепечатывают паттерн из любимого источника и все.

Есть DLL, из которой вызывается одна единственная функция, код следующий:

```
public class U2KApi:IDisposable
{
    private const string FunctionName = "fname";
    private const string B5 = "param1";
    private const int B6 = param2;

    public delegate int MainFuncDelegate(int b1, int b2, int b3, int b4, string b5, int b6);
    private bool _disposedValue;
    private SafeLibraryHandle _safeLibraryHandle;
    private MainFuncDelegate _mainFuncDelegate;

    public U2KApi()
    {
        var fileName = "dllname.dll";

        _safeLibraryHandle = Kernel32Dll.LoadLibrary(fileName);

        if (_safeLibraryHandle.IsInvalid)
        {
            var hrForLastWin32Error = Marshal.GetHRForLastWin32Error();
            Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(hrForLastWin32Error);
        }

        var procAddress = Kernel32Dll.GetProcAddress(_safeLibraryHandle, FunctionName);

        if (procAddress == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            _safeLibraryHandle.Close();
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }

        var delegateForFunctionPointer = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer<MainFuncDelegate>(procAddress);

        _mainFuncDelegate = delegateForFunctionPointer;
    }

    public int MainFunc(int b1, int b2, int b3, int b4)
    {
        return _mainFuncDelegate(b1, b2, b3, b4, B5, B6);
    }

    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_disposedValue) return;

        if (disposing)
        {
            if (_safeLibraryHandle != null)
            {
                if (!_safeLibraryHandle.IsClosed)
                {
                    _safeLibraryHandle.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        _safeLibraryHandle = null;
        _mainFuncDelegate = null;

        _disposedValue = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    ~U2KApi()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }
}

static class Kernel32Dll
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern SafeLibraryHandle LoadLibrary(string fileName);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(SafeLibraryHandle hModule, string procname);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);
}

class SafeLibraryHandle : SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid
{
    private SafeLibraryHandle() : base(true)
    {
    }

    protected override bool ReleaseHandle()
    {
        return Kernel32Dll.FreeLibrary(handle);
    }
}
```

Вопросы примерно следующие:

- Нужно ли закрывать `SafeHandle` внутри if (disposing) - видел примеры обратного, когда проверка на disposing опускалась, и, честно, не понимаю, как правильно. Зачем тогда городить огород из `Dispose(bool)`?
- Нужно ли присваивать null `_safeLibraryHandle` и `_mainFuncDelegate` - памяти много не съедят же?
- Если нет, можно ли всё упростить?

UPD. Почитал ответы VladD, пытался думать. Насколько я понял, так как handle обернут в `SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid`, то всё можно свести к простому освобождению `_safeLibraryHandle` в обычном Dispose(), выкинув финализатор и перегруженный `Dispose(bool)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда вы используете `SafeHandle`, классический паттерн Dispose помножается на ноль, и вне наследников `SafeHandle` все методы `Dispose` должны быть простыми методами, которые вызывают `Dispose` на приватных членах, реализующих `IDisposable`. Никаких финализаторов в коде быть не должно.

С точки зрения инкапсуляции ваш код для загрузки библиотеки и проверки ошибок я бы переместил в `SafeLibraryHandle`. По возможности весь грязный интероп лучше держать в одном месте.